# React Native: What is the default font that react native uses?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to make a graphic using the same font as the one being used by default in React Native but I don't know what the font is.

Anyone know?

Answer (score 16):

The default font that React Native uses is `"System font"`, which refers to the font used by the operating system on which the app is running.

On iOS, the system font is `San Francisco`, and on Android, it is `Roboto`.

Answer (score 13):

Pretty sure React-Native just uses the default font family for each platform. So that's San Francisco on IOS and Roboto for Android.

Comment: You are right about React Native uses system font but since iOS 9 default system font is San Francisco